# Android photo filter

Tags: android, image, performance, image-processing

I'm trying to make some photo filters in Android and I have code

```
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            // get pixel color
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);
do some work here
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
```

And this is very very slow and it is impossible to do anything.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Use Color Matrices. Instead of working a pixel at a time in a nested loop, they work on the whole image at once. You can do many effects - like Greyscale Conversion, Sepia Toning, Invert, Posterization, Brightness Adjustment, ...

Comment: Can I do every possible effect with Color Matrices?
Can you give me some tutorial about Color Matrices?

Comment: You can make color effects. Google `android colormatrix`. Google `ColorMatrix` for finding more ColorMatrices.

Answer (score 0):

Android's Media Effects framework allows developers to easily apply lots of impressive visual effects to photos and videos. As the framework uses the GPU to perform all its image processing operations, it can only accept OpenGL textures as its input. See [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-media-effects-with-opengl-es--cms-23650) to know  how to use OpenGL ES 2.0 to convert a drawable resource into a texture and then use the framework to apply various effects to it. And I guess it is quicker than your current method!